# Can I "fix" Xserves' IP addresses on a local network?

Tags: network, time-capsule, xserve

Home/office environment:

- 27" iMac with dual cores running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and
- 2 Xserves each with 2 quad cores running Mac OS X Server 10.6.8
- Time capsule.
- Networking by ethernet

Can I "fix" the IP address of the Xserves on this network so that even if the servers get turned off and on they will always have the same IP address?

This would seem to simplify some SSH it looks like I need to do to run scripts remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - set up a DHCP reservation on your TimeCapsule using the Airport Utility of your choice. I prefer using a client ID so you can easily change things when you get a new server, but typing the MAC address in also works.